# Runtime Error upon returning pointer

Tags: c++, string, memory, struct, destructor

Here's a method which reads binary data from file and then returns pointer to object.

```
Database* Database::open(const char *path)
{
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(path, ios::in | ios::binary);
    if(!ifs)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to open database." << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    config_vars cfg;
    ifs.read((char*)&cfg, sizeof(config_vars));
    if ( (ifs.rdstate() & std::ifstream::failbit ) != 0 )
    {
        cerr << "Failed to read database file." << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    ifs.close();

    Database *db = new Database();
    db->config = cfg;
    db->db_path = string(path);
    return db;
};
```

The call stack shows that it's indicated by destroying string member of config_vars struct, which is defined as following:

```
struct config_vars
{
    string name;
    string author;
    int date;
};
```

I can't really understand what causes the access violation. Also the method is static, if it matters.

Call Stack:

```
msvcp100d.dll!std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all()  Line 201 + 0x12 bytes  C++
    NoDB.exe!std::_String_val<char,std::allocator<char> >::~_String_val<char,std::allocator<char> >()  Line 478 + 0xb bytes C++
    NoDB.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >()  Line 754 + 0xf bytes C++
    NoDB.exe!config_vars::~config_vars()  + 0x54 bytes  C++
>   NoDB.exe!Database::open(const char * path)  Line 24 + 0x1b bytes    C++
```

Comment: What access violation? You haven't shown anything here. What is `Database`? What is the error? How do you run this code?

Comment: @Mat: What the heck does this have to do with serialising vectors? Please do not abuse your dupe-hammer.

Comment: @Selenir: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before proceeding.

Comment: @Mat: But it is not the exact same _question_. You cannot just dupe-close everything that may have similar answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The std::string class is not much more than a data member with a pointer.  So whatever you're reading into cfg with `ifs.read((char*)&cfg, sizeof(config_vars));` is setting the pointers to completely invalid pointers.  That's the source of your access violation.

What you need to do is read each member of cfg individually.  Depending on the format of the cfg file, you might be able to do something like:

```
ifs >> cfg.name;
ifs >> cfg.author;
ifs >> date;
```

but it probably won't be quite that easy.

Anyways, that's why you're getting the access violation.  You'll need to find a different way, but that would be a different question!  Good luck!

Comment: But the problem is that it does correctly read data from file, access violation happens when method returns pointer and all the local variables are destroyed, as it is shown in the call stack.

Comment: @Selenir - `config_vars cfg;`  This needs to be destructed at the end of the function, and your "read" messed it up.  That's the simple explanation.

Comment: No, it's not reading correctly.  You may not get an error code, but you're stomping all over memory when you do it the way you're doing.  The error isn't manifesting itself until the stack is cleaning up.  The string destructor is trying to delete a pointer that's pointing to something completely invalid.

Answer (score 0):

C++ objects aren't strings. They're not just flat collections of bytes. You cannot, in general, deserialise them in this manner. You will need a proper serialisation library.